# Translating Qt applications

Tags: qt, translation, qt-linguist

I need to have my application translated into many different languages, I have the translators and know that I can use Qt Linguist.  However as far as I can tell I have to package up Linguist myself and ship it out to the translators.

Is there a web-based solution or do other package Qt Linguist with the ts files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to package it up yourself. However, while browsing qt-apps.org the other day I did come across [Qt Linguist Download](http://www.qt-apps.org/content/show.php/Qt+Linguist+Download?content=89360) which seems to be a packaged version of Linguist designed to address exactly this need. I have not actually used this myself - our translation is done in-house so we have not had this particular issue.